User ID mismatch with OAuth 2.0 Authorization
I am using OAuth 2.0 Authorization (marklogic-xquery-oauth2) with MarkLogic 11.1.0.
For a request to the app-server with application-level authentication and default user as oauth-anon (details in the linked github repo), ID of the user name returned by xdmp:get-request-username doesn't match the user ID returned by xdmp:get-request-user.
Also, no user can be found in the Security database with the user ID returned by xdmp:get-request-user.
User corresponding to the name returned by xdmp:get-request-username does exist in the Security database.
Can someone please elaborate on this behaviour?

FYI - MarkLogic now has Oauth 2.0 support https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/release-notes/en/new-features-in-marklogic-11/oauth-2-0-external-authentication.html and with 11.2.0 JWT https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/release-notes/en/new-features-in-marklogic-11-2/oauth-2-0-jwt-and-oidc-support.html
